# How to convert string stored in variable of javascript directly to object property?

Tags: javascript

```
var str="firstname";
var obj={};
obj.str="john";
```

I want to create property firstname but i want to create it by the variable name  like obj.str not like obj.firstname  here problem is obj.str create property str not firstname.
i want to create property like this because it will later help me to create property by joining two string .

Comment: You should be able to use the `obj[str]` notation

Comment: obj[str]="abv "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this with `[]` notation.
See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors) when to use dot(`.`) or bracket(`[]`) notation for javascript.

```js
var str = "firstname";
var obj = {};
obj[str] = "john";
console.log(obj);
```